# Cannot call some methods in interface after instantiating the objects in Java

Tags: java

I have this code sample as you can see. But when I try to compile, it gives an error saying in `id.input` the object reference variable `id` cannot be found. Can someone please help me?

```
interface IDisplay{
    void print();
    void printDetails();
}

interface IInput{
    void input();
}

class Book implements IDisplay,IInput{
    int bookID;
    String title,publisher;
    public void print(){

    }
    public void printDetails(){

    }
    public void input(){

    }
}

class Student implements IDisplay,IInput{
    int studentID;
    public void print(){

    }
    public void printDetails(){

    }
    public void input(){

    }
}

class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IDisplay id=new Student();
                id.print();
                id.printDetails();
                id.input();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Student` instance will be able to call all methods of `IInput` and `IDisplay` method but, it depends how you manipulate it

Because you stored if in `IDisplay`, the methods of `IInput` are not *visible*

---

*Solution :*

1. Cast in `IInput`

   ```
   IDisplay id = new Student();
   id.print();
   id.printDetails();
   ((IInput) id).input();      // or  ((Student) id).input();
   ```
2. Store in `Student` type

   ```
   Student id = new Student();
   id.print();
   id.printDetails();
   id.input();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Interface `IDisplay` has only two methods `print` and `printDetails` and the method `input` is in the interface `IInput`.

In your code, the object `id` is of *type* `IDisplay` (even though it holds a *reference* to a `Student` object) and hence you can only call the methods on the interface `IDisplay`.

You either have to cast the `id` object to either `Student` or `IInput` to call the `input` method

```
((Student)id).input();
((IInput)id).input();
```

Or

have `id` as type `Student`.

However, it could be argued that the former violates some OO principles as a `IDisplay` has to only be an `IDisplay` and an `IInput` has to be only an `IInput`

Answer (score 2):

At compile stage, the compiler only knows that `id`'s reference type is `IDisplay`, it does not know `id`'s runtime type is `Student`.

Since `IDisplay` does not have method `input`, you got compile error. To make it compile, you can cast it explictly:

```
((Student)id).input();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `id` is of type `IDisplay` and not of type `Student`.

`IDisplay` does not have method `input()`

If you want to invoke a method from `Student`, you can cast it as `Student`:

```
((Student)id).input();
```

or cast as IInput:

```
((IInput)id).input();
```

or instantiate as Student:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.input();
```

Answer (score 1):

when you instantiate an object (id) type of IDisplay, cause JVM casts it to an object, IDisplay of type.
so it has been instantiated only with implemented methods of interface IDisplay despite you used the constructor of class Student which implements IDisplay and IInput.
if you intend object id to access to implemented methods of the both interfaces IDisplay and IInput, you should modify your code to:

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student id = new Student();
                id.print();
                id.printDetails();
                id.input();
    }
}
```